# Google Smart Home Actions Toggle Trait for Horizontal & Vertical Swing

Tags: google-assistant

I am toggling horizontal swing and vertical swing in Hindi language, but assistant is not taking my command and always take me to a web page.

English Utterance: Start Horizontal Swing on Bedroom A/C. (working)
Hindi Utterance: बैडरूम एसी के हॉरिजॉन्टल स्विंग को चालू कर दो.(not working)

I have given all the possible commands in Hindi related to toggle but its not working. Please help me out from this.

Result : Command is to be executed when i am toggling Horizontal swing and vertical swing.

Below is my Google SYNC response:

{
"requestId": "11311483680465073646",
"payload": {
"agentUserId": "123",
"devices": [

```
        {
            "id": "stest240",
            "name": {
                "name": "Bedroom A/C",
                "defaultNames": [
                    "Smart Air Conditioner"
                ]
            },
            "type": "action.devices.types.THERMOSTAT",
            "traits": [
                "action.devices.traits.OnOff",
                "action.devices.traits.TemperatureSetting",                   
                "action.devices.traits.Toggles"
            ],
            "willReportState": false,
            "deviceInfo": {
                "manufacturer": "smart-home",
                "model": "hs1234",
                "hwVersion": "3.2",
                "swVersion": "11.4"
            },
            "attributes": {
                "availableThermostatModes": [
                    "cool",
                    "dry",
                    "fan-only"
                ],
                "thermostatTemperatureUnit": "C",
                "thermostatTemperatureRange": {
                    "minThresholdCelsius": 16,
                    "maxThresholdCelsius": 30
                },                   
                "availableToggles": [
                    {
                        "name": "horizontalswing",
                        "name_values": [
                            {
                                "name_synonym": [
                                    "horizontal swing"
                                ],
                                "lang": "en"
                            },
                            {
                                "name_synonym": [
                                        "हॉरिजोंटल स्विंग",
                                        "हॉरिजॉन्टल स्विंग"
                                ],
                                "lang": "hi"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "verticalswing",
                        "name_values": [
                            {
                                "name_synonym": [
                                    "vertical swing"
                                ],
                                "lang": "en"
                            },
                            {
                                "name_synonym": [
                                        "वर्टिकल स्विंग",
                                        "वर्टीकल स्विंग"
                                ],
                                "lang": "hi"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Comment: Could you make more obvious how this is a programming question according to [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ? I have the impression that this is about configuring the assistant, not about programming.

Comment: what i have to provide for analysis?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have added my code for analysis.